# Blocking the download of data in a specific version of the API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have two versions of the API

1 version has endpoint and the other version does not have it

I set the latest version of the API as the default:

```
services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
            {
                o.ReportApiVersions = true;
                o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                o.ApiVersionSelector = new CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector(o);
                o.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(new QueryStringApiVersionReader(), new HeaderApiVersionReader("api-version"));
            });
```

In this case, when I call the query without defining which version to use, it gets data from version 1

I would like to receive information when calling the default API version that the version does not support this endpoint. At this point, it calls version 1

I should get information that the version does not support this endpoint

**Version 1 should only work if it is appropriately marked in the query header**

Comment: Share us your two versions api. What do you mean by `1 version has endpoint and the other version does not have it`? What is your current request and your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post a sample of the two versions of the API, because the behaviour of the `ApiVersioning` middleware sounds like it does exactly what you want. Let's work a simple example to demonstrate how missing endpoints are handled.

Here's a pair of controllers just dumped in a default new .NET Core Web API project:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ApiVersioning.Controllers.Api.V1
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("validforboth")]
        public ActionResult<string> ValidForBoth()
        {
            return "Version 1 API";
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("validversion1only")]
        public ActionResult<string> ValidVersion1Only()
        {
            return "This endpoint won't exist on API version 2 - try it";
        }
    }
}

namespace ApiVersioning.Controllers.Api.V2
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("validforboth")]
        public ActionResult<string> ValidForBoth()
        {
            return "Version 2 API";
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("validversion2only")]
        public ActionResult<string> ValidVersion2Only()
        {
            return "This endpoint won't exist on API version 1 - try it";
        }
    }
}
```

We've got two classes, one for each version of the API annotated as version 1.0 and version 2.0. We configure the middleware exactly as you did - making version 2.0 the default:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
                .AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services
                .AddApiVersioning(o =>
                {
                    o.ReportApiVersions = true;
                    o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                    o.ApiVersionSelector = new CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector(o);
                    o.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(new QueryStringApiVersionReader(), new HeaderApiVersionReader("api-version"));
                });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Now we try calling the two API versions just using Chrome and GET requests.

### Version 1 responses (`?api-version=1.0` in query string)

**/api/values/validforboth** returns `Version 1 API`

**/api/values/validversion1only** returns `This endpoint won't exist on API version 2 - try it`

**/api/values/validversion2only** returns HTTP 400 with the following JSON body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnsupportedApiVersion",
    "message": "The HTTP resource that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:55575/api/values/validversion2only' does not support the API version '1.0'.",
    "innerError": null
  }
}
```

### Version 2 responses (either omitting `?api-version=1.0`, or specifying 2.0 explicitly)

**/api/values/validforboth** returns `Version 2 API`

**/api/values/validversion1only** returns HTTP 400 with the following JSON body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnsupportedApiVersion",
    "message": "The HTTP resource that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:55575/api/values/validversion1only' is not supported.",
    "innerError": null
  }
}
```

**/api/values/validversion2only** returns `This endpoint won't exist on API version 1 - try it`

The clients of your version 1 API will see a 400 if they try to hit an endpoint defined only in version 2 - similarly, clients of your version 2 API will see a 400 if they try to hit an endpoint defined only in version 1.